# MobileFirst 7.1 Client Log Device Info - UNKNOWN

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using MobileFirst Version 7.1.0.00.20161118-2214. In this fixpack version my apps started pushing client logs as UNKNOWN in both android and iOS. Not sure whats the issue.

> "appName": "UNKNOWN",
>            "appVersion": "UNKNOWN",
>            "deviceId": "UNKNOWN",
>            "model": "UNKNOWN",
>            "systemName": "UNKNOWN",
>            "systemVersion": "UNKNOWN"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a regression in the latest iFix release. You know the drill - will require a PMR to provide you with a fix.

Try restarting the server, though?